# How to read latest index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, metricbeat

In my ElasticSearch, a new index for metricbeat is created with date suffix. i.e 'metricbeat-7.1-2019.12.20'. Now I am trying to read system parameter from the latest created index but I am not sure how to do that.

```
 var nodes = new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri(_options.Value.ElasticSearchUrl),
            };
            connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
            string indexName = "metricbeat*";
            connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DefaultIndex(indexName);
            elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            string[] systemFields = new string[]
            {
                "system.memory.*"
            };
            var elasticResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
                .DocValueFields(dvf => dvf.Fields(systemFields)));
```

elasticResponse gives me data but it shows the older date in timestamp.

Please suggest.

```
  string[] systemFields = new string[]
            {
                "system.memory.actual.used.pct",
                "system.cpu.total.norm.pct",
                "system.load.5",
                "docker.diskio.summary.bytes"
            };
            var elasticResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
                .DocValueFields(dvf => dvf.Fields(systemFields))
                .Aggregations(ag => ag.Max("last_process_time", sa => sa
                    .Field("@timestamp")))
                );
```

Comment: Give the exact index name and don't use wildcards as you have used above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cat indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) will help you find index you are looking for by using creation date as sort parameter.

```
    await client.Indices.CreateAsync("metricbeat-7.1-2019.12.20", create => create);
    await client.Indices.CreateAsync("metricbeat-7.1-2019.12.21", create => create);

    var response = await client.Cat.IndicesAsync(i => i.Index("metricbeat-7.1-*")
        .Headers("index", "creation.date")
        .SortByColumns("creation.date"));

    Console.WriteLine(response.Records.LastOrDefault()?.Index);
```

Output:

```
metricbeat-7.1-2019.12.21
```

Hopefully, you defined [ILM policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management-api.html) for your indices and my solution won't retrieve 
thousands of indices information from elasticsearch.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your suggestion, I add "sort":[
    {
        "@timestamp": {"order": "desc"}
    }
  ] to my query and it worked fine  but not found any way to add it in NEST query. I use this in NEST .Sort(sh => sh.Descending(d => d.timestamp())) but timestamp not exist there.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were looking for a way to get the latest index you can query on.

Comment: You can just pass timestamp field name as a string `s.Sort(so => so.Descending("@timestamp"))`.

Comment: Hi @Rob, this sort statement gives me multiple record of one metric with different timestamp, yes they are sorted, but I want each metric once with latest date only.

Comment: Doesn’t metric beat document contain all of the latest metrics, so simply get top first from the response?

Comment: The actual query which I have is in my post above, which have 4 different metric and each should belong to different latest document. But my current query return no data.